# adding play-services-maps dependancy auto adds glEsVersion 2.0 requirement

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-manifest

I'd like to integrate with `Google Play Services Maps` module.

Since the maps manifest declare:

```
<uses-feature    
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

`Gradle`'s [manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) adds this block to the resulting manifest making my app not supported on devices running `OpenGL 1.0`, however my Maps feature is not mandatory, and I do want to support these devices.

I've tried adding to my own manifest one of these:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00010000"
    android:required="false" />
```

or

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00010000"
    android:required="false"
    tools:replace="glEsVersion,required" />
```

or

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00010000"
    android:required="false"
    tools:node="remove"
    tools:replace="glEsVersion,required"/>
```

But nothing works, either it automatically chooses the one with the highest value (2.0), or it adds both blocks to the resulting manifest, still making my app require 2.0

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve it using `build.gradle` hacks, by manually overriding the merged manifest source.

However I would prefer a more elegant way using `Gradle's manifest merger` tools (`tools:node`, `tools:replace`, etc.)

I removed the `glEsVersion` from `AndroidManifest`, and added the following to my `build.gradle`:

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.processManifest.doLast {
                def manifestOutFile = output.processManifest.manifestOutputFile
                def newFileContents = manifestOutFile.getText('UTF-8').replace("android:glEsVersion=\"0x00020000\"", "android:glEsVersion=\"0x00010000\"")
                manifestOutFile.write(newFileContents, 'UTF-8')
            }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gradle 3+ doesn't support `manifestOutputFile` anymore so the code need to be changed little bit:

`def manifestOutFile = new File(output.processManifest.manifestOutputDirectory, "AndroidManifest.xml")`

Comment: @Buthrakaur - I didn't encounter this issue on versions 3+ until I tried to upgrade to 3.3.
When i try your solution, I get an error - see my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551055/unable-to-overwrite-the-manifest-with-gradle-plugin-3-3