# Unable to overwrite the manifest with gradle plugin 3.3

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, gradle-plugin

This is basically a copy of the text that I wrote in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123893861)

Any help would be appreciated:

I'm trying to upgrade my project to gradle plugin 3.3 w/ gradle 4.10.1 and my build fails with the following error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':main:processDebugManifest'.

  > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /main/property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, transform(property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout$FixedDirectory, /main/build))))/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

my code is identical to the code here - https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#variant_api under "manifestOutputFile is no longer available"

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.processManifest.doLast {
            // Stores the path to the maifest.
            String manifestPath = "$manifestOutputDirectory/AndroidManifest.xml"
            // Stores the contents of the manifest.
            def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText()
...
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the line that produces the error -

```
def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText()
```

**Update:**
tried the solution suggested in the comment below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537506/2482564) and got the following error

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ‘:main:processDebugManifest’.
>     Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout$DefaultDirectoryVar, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

```
def outputDir = manifestOutputDirectory
File directory
if (outputDir instanceof File) {
    directory = outputDir
} else {
    directory = outputDir.get().asFile
}

String manifestPath = directory.toString() + "/AndroidManifest.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`String manifestPath = "$manifestOutputDirectory/AndroidManifest.xml"`

with

`String manifestPath = new File(output.processManifest.manifestOutputDirectory.get().asFile, "AndroidManifest.xml")`

Comment: Hi there! Can you give us more information on what your solution does and why is solves the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue as described above. Not gradle expert. This started happening when I upgraded gradle to 4.10.2. After quite some time spent googling and looking into gradle documention for a solution, this was eventually what worked for me.